# Losing on words in DTM matrix

Tags: r, analytics, text-mining, topic-modeling

I am not able to pick up a few important words while creating a document-term matrix in R. I even tried removing all the filters on the corpus,i.e., tried dtm on the raw file but still I am not able to capture it. Please help.
Let's say the text is something like this: 
"I like to read DC comics because of batman adventures". Here I am not able to capture DC in my DTM matrix.

Comment: It's very hard to tell whats wrong until you post your codes and relevant error as well...

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust your the default settings of `tm`. Just using `DocumentTermMatrix()` or `TermDocumentMatrix` will remove any words smaller than 3.

You need to use adjust the wordLengths option in the `control` options when you create the dtm. So in your case 1 or 2 would capture what you want. The reason for 3 is that it gets rid of short words, like "a", "in", "or", etc.

```
DocumentTermMatrix(corpus, control=list(wordLengths = c(1, Inf)))
```